# Zurb Foundation 5 'silent' placeholder classes?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

So I know you can extend Foundation classes once you have the Foundation scss/css included and I know you can include the classes to the dom (OOCSS style) but here's my use-case:

I have style sheet, `menus.scss`. This is compiled into `app.css` along with Foundation.scss.

I can use the `@extend` here because I'm including Foundation before it.

```
#menu {
    @extend .top-bar;
}
```

#### THE PROBLEM

Now, say I want to compile a separate sheet (because maybe it's only included on *some* pages)

Now if I `@import` Foundation into this stylesheet I will end up with the framework included twice (which is crazy of course.)

**So...** maybe a solution would be to have a version of the Framework that works on silent classes EG: `%top-bar` so I can include Foundation everywhere without fear of duplicating lots of code. I know there are some base components that will need to be included globally so that the sub-classes will work but how else can I do it?

To my knowledge silent frameworks don't exist so I'm looking for alternatives..

Ideas?

Comment: `@include` is for mixins, do you mean `@extend`?  Have you tried what you are suggesting?

Comment: I did mean @extend - corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @cimmanon - I don't know a way of trying my idea without converting the Framework to % placeholders by hand? I just can't get my head around how I can use the framework across multiple stylesheets?

Comment: I just don't see what the problem is.  If you have a file that imports foundation, menu, and sidebar then menu and sidebar should be able to extend anything that's part of foundation.

Comment: Yes, in that instance (all compiling to a single sheet) it's fine. However I then want a second (third/fourth) stylesheet that compiles separately to app.scss (because it's only included on pages with the user menu for example) but want to use Foundation in there too. Maybe the question needs some refining. (My head is fried after trying to get this working today)

Comment: I don't feel that splitting files in this way is really useful, but you don't have to include Foundation in its entirety:  just import exactly the files you need that contain the selectors necessary.

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon - I have a global stylesheet and then page-specific ones to avoid bloat and I'd like to use Foundation in both. Just frustrating.

Comment: Could you only include the components of foundation that you're using for that stylesheet? For example, just @import "foundation/_side-nav.scss", etc. This would still be repeating some styles, but would save on a lot of bloat.

Comment: Cheers @sdsanders, there will still be overlap sadly. I guess I'll just have to compile all stylesheets into one. That seems the least bloat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will be perfect if you can isolate css critical to the initial page layout like `grid`, `type`, `visibility` components and inline them in to the page head or, if you have a ton of pages, in  css file with the final size under 1-1.5k(really hard to do).
Then you can just defer auxiliary css and their size wont matter much.

Or You can use some css cleaner tool to remove selector  duplicates or just make your own, it's pretty simple since the entire blocks of css will match.

Comment: Cheers @JAre - it's a tricky one for sure. If I was using it in the DOM classes it wouldn't be an issue but obviously Foundation has it's own variables earlier in the code so actually pulling a section out is impossible. Not to worry, onwards and upwards :)

Comment: @rob_was_taken if you use same setting for all stylesheets it's not a problem.